# How to load gif image and control that in ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, startup, gif

In my application i want load the gif images in my view and also controls stop and continue animating.[image: when i click pause button application should stop animating and when again click start animating]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly follow the below tutorial that may help you.
 http://anand3777.blogspot.in/2014/07/gif-image-loading.html

Step 1:

```
   Download library from below url and add it on your project.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5JC34Lt79ctamtOVTV6SHhzOVU&usp=sharing
```

Step 2:

```
  Import the file on your "viewController.h" like below.
  //gifImage//
  #import "SCGIFImageView.h"
 //gifImage//
```

Step 3:

```
    Create object like given below on your "viewController.h".
    //gifImage//
    IBOutlet SCGIFImageView* _gifImageView;
    IBOutlet UIButton* _button;
    //gifImage//
```

Step 4:

```
   Create ibaction on your "viewController".
   //gifImage//
    - (IBAction)controlAnimate:(id)sender;
   //gifImage//
```

Step 5:

```
   Add the following code were you want to use gif image
  //gifImage//
  //load url gif image
  NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.co.in/anim.gif"];
  NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
  /*
   //load local gif image
   NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1.gif" ofType:nil];
   NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
 */
  _gifImageView = [[SCGIFImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 70, 75, 75)] ;
 [_gifImageView setData:imageData];
 [self.view addSubview:_gifImageView];
 //gifImage//
```

Step 6:

```
   Add the following code for stop/start animating
  //gifImage//
  - (IBAction)controlAnimate:(id)sender{
     _gifImageView.animating = !_gifImageView.animating;

     if (_gifImageView.animating) {
         [_button setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     } else {
         [_button setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
  }
 //gifImage//


[1]: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5JC34Lt79ctamtOVTV6SHhzOVU&usp=sharing
```

Comment: Kindly add detail to your code instead of saying just do this. Explanations make answers good and format correctly.

Comment: Mr  Popeye. I wll try to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use Latest GIF Class from https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage 
It is easy to use and memory friendly.

In your code, `#import "FLAnimatedImage.h"`, create an image from an animated GIF, and setup the image view to display it:

```
FLAnimatedImage *image         = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"]]];
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animatedImage        = image;
imageView.frame                = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0); //As your Wish you can set frame
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

or If you are using Bundle gif file then

```
NSURL *url                     = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"loading_01" withExtension:@"gif"];

FLAnimatedImage *image         = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
FLAnimatedImageView *imageView = [[FLAnimatedImageView alloc] init];
imageView.animatedImage        = image;
imageView.frame                = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0); //As your Wish you can set frame
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```